# Function model in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-uml, function, functional

I want to make a simple function model like in the picture. How would I do that? The docs of `tikz-uml` don't really help in this case.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You should add your code to show what you tried. Is there something specific that did not work or that you do not know how to do?

Comment: My bad. I thought of using statecharts, but in my case we explicitly need to use the given format just like in the picture.  I thought of using an uml simple class and using this as a node in an tikzpicture "automaton", but I'd still have problems with the arrows, since I would only be able to connect nodes but not use the arrows as an indication for an input/output. There was also this example I found online https://texample.net/tikz/examples/epc-flow-charts/ however I don't know how I'd put this  kind of node network in a bigger uml class (in this case "BoostedBreak")

Comment: I suggest to spend some time on tikz via ctan.org. Here is an example which comes close to what you want https://texample.net/tikz/examples/quantum-circuit/ . E.g. look up the approaches both in the minimal introduction and in the big one. Tikz can create what you want, once you learned some basics.

Comment: Will do thank you very much

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. One possibility is to draw the big rectangle `on background layer` in a `scope` using `fit`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[mybox/.style={draw, ultra thick, gray!80, fill=gray!20, rounded corners, text=black, minimum height=1cm}, font=\sffamily]
\node[mybox](conv) at (0,1.5){Converter(-n) c};
\node[mybox](addf) at (4,0){AddForces add};
\draw[latex-, ultra thick] (conv.west)--++(-1.5,0)coordinate(RR){}node[above left]{(N F) b};
\draw[-latex, ultra thick] (addf.east)--++(1.5,0)node[above]{(N F) r};
\draw[-latex, ultra thick] (conv.east)--++(.75,0)|-(addf.170);
\draw[latex-, ultra thick] (addf.190)--(addf.190-|RR)node[above left]{(N F) d};
\scoped[on background layer]\node[mybox, fit=(conv)(addf), inner sep=5mm, yshift=2mm](BB){};
\node[below right=1mm] at (BB.north west){BoostedBreak(n)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your idea, I'll try it out with a more advanced example